# Case when in sql oracle

Tags: oracle, plsql, case, oracle-sqldeveloper

I am new in sql oracle and I have a problem with how to use case when here, for example this is the case :

1. if transaction_type RECEIVE then receipt date - promised date
2. if receipt date > promised date then receipt date - promised date
3. if receipt date <= promised date then null
4. if not yet receive or transaction_type DELIVER then sysdate - promised date

   ```
   CASE WHEN transaction_type ='RECEIVE' THEN to_char(creation_date, 'DD-MON-YYYY') – to_char(promised_date, 'DD-MON-YYYY')
     WHEN to_char(creation_date, 'DD-MON-YYYY') > to_char(promised_date, 'DD-MON-YYYY') THEN to_char(creation_date, 'DD-MON-YYYY') – to_char(promised_date, 'DD-MON-YYYY')
     WHEN to_char(creation_date, 'DD-MON-YYYY') <= to_char(promised_date, 'DD-MON-YYYY') THEN null
     WHEN transaction_type ='DELIVER' THEN to_char(sysdate, 'DD-MON-YYYY') - to_char(promised_date, 'DD-MON-YYYY') END AS delay_day
   ```

> > ORA-00911: invalid character 00911. 00000 -  "invalid character"
> > *Cause:    The identifier name started with an ASCII character other than a
> > letter or a number. After the first character of the identifier
> > name, ASCII characters are allowed including "$", "#" and "_".
> > Identifiers enclosed in double quotation marks may contain any
> > character other than a double quotation. Alternate quotation
> > marks (q'#...#') cannot use spaces, tabs, or carriage returns as
> > delimiters. For all other contexts, consult the SQL Language
> > Reference Manual.
> > *Action:   Check the Oracle identifier naming convention. If you are
> > attempting to provide a password in the IDENTIFIED BY clause of
> > a CREATE USER or ALTER USER statement, then it is recommended to
> > always enclose the password in double quotation marks because
> > characters other than the double quotation are then allowed.
> > Error at Line: 21 Column: 94

and this is the error and I have no idea what's wrong with this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like you copy/pasted code from some *fancy* text editor (MS Word, perhaps?) which uses *fancy* characters for single and double quotes, as well as **minus** signs. If converted to a "normal" minus `-`, then it *should* be OK:

```
      CASE
          WHEN transaction_type = 'RECEIVE'
          THEN
               TO_CHAR (creation_date, 'DD-MON-YYYY')
             - TO_CHAR (promised_date, 'DD-MON-YYYY')         --> this minus
          WHEN TO_CHAR (creation_date, 'DD-MON-YYYY') >
               TO_CHAR (promised_date, 'DD-MON-YYYY')
          THEN
               TO_CHAR (creation_date, 'DD-MON-YYYY')
             - TO_CHAR (promised_date, 'DD-MON-YYYY')         --> and this minus
          WHEN TO_CHAR (creation_date, 'DD-MON-YYYY') <=
               TO_CHAR (promised_date, 'DD-MON-YYYY')
          THEN
             NULL
          WHEN transaction_type = 'DELIVER'
          THEN
               TO_CHAR (SYSDATE, 'DD-MON-YYYY')
             - TO_CHAR (promised_date, 'DD-MON-YYYY')
       END AS delay_day
```

**However**: what do you expect to get as a result? Subtraction of two **strings** is ridiculous. What is `'A' - '23FX__#'`? If you wanted to subtract **dates**, sure - why not - result will be number of days between those two dates.

Furthermore, comparing strings won't work either in most cases.

It means that your should - perhaps - remove TO_CHAR entirely.

```
        CASE
          WHEN transaction_type = 'RECEIVE'
          THEN
             creation_date - promised_date
          WHEN creation_date > promised_date
          THEN
             creation_date - promised_date
          WHEN creation_date <= promised_date
          THEN
             NULL
          WHEN transation_type = 'DELIVER'
          THEN
             SYSDATE - promised_date
       END AS delay_day
```